# rCharts formatting

Tags: r, rcharts

I'm bit struggling with `rCharts` formatting, it's part of my part of presentation and I need to go with `Highcharts`, and it's part of shiny/reactive. I can not change these rules.
I would like to format my h1 to be similar to that commented `hPlot` so I'll have my YYYYMM on x. I've checked on Internet but all this info is too technical for me. I don't have time resources for this piece.

```
library(rCharts)

x <- data.frame(PRODUCT=factor(c("ALPHA", "ALPHA","BRAVO","ALPHA","ALPHA")), 
                YYYYMM= factor(c("2/1/2015","3/1/2015","4/1/2015","5/1/2015","6/1/2015")),
                MEM_COUNT=c(44,22,37,76,97))
## none of this formatting work
x$YYYYMM <- as.Date(x$YYYYMM)
x$YYYYMM = strftime(strptime(x$YYYYMM, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), format = "%b/%y") 

###  hPlot(MEM_COUNT ~ YYYYMM, data=x, type="line")  #<@>< good sample!!

### output$chart <- renderChart2({
  h1 <- Highcharts$new()
  h1$chart(type = "spline")
  h1$series(data = x$MEM_COUNT, dashStyle = "longdash")
  h1$legend(symbolWidth = 80)
  h1$xAxis(Title= list(text="Months"),type="datetime")
  h1
###})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mario, the first step is to change the Date to milliseconds and don’t switch to scientific notation, as Highcharts/javascript expects the date/time represented in milliseconds.

```
options(scipen = 13)
x$YYYYMM <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(x$YYYYMM, format='%m/%d/%Y')) * 1000
```

Now, you can build the chart. Using your example data we will plot the MEM_COUNT vs. YYYYMM, grouped by PRODUCT. ( as product ‘Alpha’ has only 1 data point it doesn’t make much sense, but anyway..)

```
h1 <- Highcharts$new()
h1 <- hPlot(MEM_COUNT ~ YYYYMM, data = x, 
      group = 'PRODUCT', 
      type = "spline" 
      )
h1$xAxis(type="datetime", labels = list(
  format = '{value:%b-%Y}'))
h1
```

By changing the ‘labels’ values you can format the x-axis to your liking.

[image]

Comment: Gracias, hvollmeier !